# I'm trying to find a way to log the command block output on a Minecraft Bedrock Realm

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've been messing around with command blocks recently, and I need to be able to 'log' my command block output.

I can see the last output it had

> 'Gave 1 diamond to JackOBoi04'  *(example)*

but I am trying to find a way to take said output, and log it in a book, or something like so even when I'm **offline**, when I come back online I can look back at the **list of** said **command block's output**, from when I was offline.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Besides for a simple succeeded or failed, you cannot read output from a command block.

Perhaps you could use the `/clone` command to clone a ton of different command blocks so you can go and look through all the copies but that is pretty unreasonable.

Comment: But does the /clone command keep the command block's previous output? Or do you mean make a copy of the command block 10 times, and run each command block at a 6 minute interval of each other, going back to the beginning of the line every hour? It's not a bad idea but setting up a 6 minute timer in between each command block could be complicated...

Comment: @JackOBoi04 `/clone`ing the command block will keep its data, so I just meant copy it to a storage spot and have it never run

Answer (score 1):

If you construct your command blocks to increment a scoreboard its a form of logging:

```
/scoreboard objectives add diamond
/scoreboard players set diamond diamond 0
```

The above commands creates a scoreboard objective 'diamond' then sets a fake player's score to 0 (as long as the name doesn't match the name of someone on the server you can make as many fake players as you want).

At the end of a chain of command logic, you could put the following command to 'log' the example you gave.

```
/scoreboard players add diamond diamond 1
```

Then when you want to view the results you could list the objectives of your fake player

```
/scoreboard players list diamond
```